# Automatically deploy website with git

Tags: php, git, deployment, bitbucket, webhooks

Today I try to deploy my website automatically. 
On our master-branch (running live on our website) is the current running website and on the develop-branch (running live on test.ourwebsite.com with password) is our current test space. 
Today we copy the files after a commit to the master/develop-branch to the server. Is it possible to deploy the files automatically after a commit to master/develop on our webserver ?

My only idea is to pull in a small interval every time our branches. But then I need for the develop-branch a really high interval.

We use currently the bitbucket.com cloud space and maybe we can use the webhooks.

Comment: Have you consider using CI server such as Jenkins to help you automate your testing (for develop) and deployment ?
Also, are you using any cloud services ? Most of it also has particular service to do such kind of things.

Comment: Jenkins is not possible, because our provider does not allow. We only use Bitbucket and our website provider

Comment: Look for another provider. Tools for Continues Integration like Jenkins are what you're looking for. There is no better solution for that.

Comment: Hmmm okay. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Definitely you can do it, even without Jenkins, but it will be a lot work and scripting which I can't imagine.

Comment: I see it. Then I have to find a provider with jenkins. My provider doesn´t provide java-apps. Or I have to host my own system.